# How to compare two list object in java?

Tags: java, collections

I write code crawl all information from website. I want when I filter and save to database, data I filter not contain database. If contain database, I don't want save it("because it duplicate").  I write code below :

```
@Data
@Entity
public class PostFeedItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "link_profile")
    private String linkProfile;
    @Column(name = "link_image")
    private String linkImage;
    @Column(name = "full_name")
    private String fullName;
    @Column(name = "content_title")
    private String contentTitle;
    @Column(name = "time_published")
    private String timePublished;
    @Column(name = "number_view")
    private String numberView;
    @Column(name = "number_comment")
    private String numberComment;
    @Column(name = "number_clip")
    private String numberClip;
    @Column(name = "point")
    private String points;
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "tags", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"))
    @Column(name = "tags_post")
    private List<String> tags = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Now i get all data from database with method :

```
public Iterable<PostFeedItem> findAllPostFeedItemInDatabase() {
        return postFeedItemRepository.findAll();
    }
```

I have a list listPostFieldItems and I want compare with postFeedItemInDatabase . If any element from listPostFieldItems match with any elements postFeedItemInDatabase , I don't want save it. If not match , I save it. I write code bellow :

```
    List<PostFeedItem> postFeedItemInDatabase = (List<PostFeedItem>) findAllPostFeedItemInDatabase();
    if(!postFeedItemInDatabase.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listPostFieldItems.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < postFeedItemInDatabase.size(); j++) {
                if((listPostFieldItems.get(i).getContentTitle().equals(postFeedItemInDatabase.get(j).getContentTitle()))) {
                    postFeedItemRepository.save(listPostFieldItems.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
    } else  {
        listPostFieldItems.forEach(postFeedItem -> {
           postFeedItemRepository.save(postFeedItem);
       });
    }
```

But it did not work. I have a question. How to compare `List<PostFeedItem> listPostFieldItems`  with `List<PostFeedItem> listItemFromDatabase` and save all object from `listPostFieldItems` if any element from `listPostFieldItems` not match `listPostFieldItems`.

Comment: if `equals` => save ? Should'nt it be the opposite ?

Comment: what are you using the inner loop for? just curious, since `j` in unused in your shared code.

Comment: @azro If every element from my list equal with every element from item in dabase, i don't want save it.

Comment: @nullpointer I have edit it

Comment: If there is ONLY ONE match => don't save ? that's what you're saying ? Because that's not at all what your code is doing

Comment: @BaoTrungTran did you run again after the edit (j) ? Also did you try sysout within the for-loop?

Comment: `int j = i+1` why are you incrementing this? Aren't these separate lists?

Comment: Thank you. If only one match = > don't save

Comment: @Nikhil because I want compare every element to every element from list ? It not correct ???

Comment: No `j=i+1` will not compare every element. `i=0,(you skip first element) j=1 to end; i=1, (you skip first two element) j=1to end ....... i=14; j=15to end (you skip 15 elements).`

Comment: `int j = i+1` is best for comparing elements within the same list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code is wrong as it should use index `j`, and you should built the loop differently, here is you have a match, so a existing record in DB, you save, you need the opposite.

There is easier ways to, for both I'd suggest to first keep a list of the `contentTitle` as it's the key to find for match/not-match

```
List<String> allTitles = postFeedItemInDatabase.stream().map(PostFeedItem::getContentTitle).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then you can

1. Remove the ones that match : from the first list that as their title in the DB title list

   ```
   listPostFieldItems.removeIf(elt -> allTitles.contains(elt.contentTitle));
   listPostFieldItems.forEach(postFeedItem -> postFeedItemRepository.save(postFeedItem));
   ```
2. Or, keep the ones that not match

   ```
   listPostFieldItems = listPostFieldItems.stream().filter(elt -> !allTitles.contains(elt.contentTitle)).collect(Collectors.toList());
   listPostFieldItems.forEach(postFeedItem -> postFeedItemRepository.save(postFeedItem));
   ```
3. Concat the operations

   ```
   listPostFieldItems.stream()
                     .filter(elt -> !allTitles.contains(elt.contentTitle))
                     .forEach(postFeedItem -> postFeedItemRepository.save(postFeedItem));
   ```

Comment: Thank you. It work perfect . Thank you so much. So i have stupid question ? In my post , we can possible used two loop i and j ?

Comment: This is the best approach. Less code and gets you the result. Using loops can lead to a lot of mistakes. Please mark this the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

1)Convert your list to java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;
2)Iterator your list;
3)Add object to your list if any element not matched.

Comment: Thank you. @azro in correct answer. But thank you for you help me

Answer (score 0):

I think your source code has 2 problems

1. For loop `postFeedItemInDatabase` must start from 0 instead of i+1.
2. If condition `listPostFieldItems.get(i).getContentTitle().equals(postFeedItemInDatabase.get(i).getContentTitle())` looks weird.

   - Condition `not equals`. If items in `listPostFieldItems` are not equals to items in `postFeedItemInDatabase` -> save().
   - `postFeedItemInDatabase.get(j)` instead of `postFeedItemInDatabase.get(i)`

Comment: Thank you. I have edit post. With answer azro, it work. Thank you for explain

Answer (score 0):

return (list1.size() == list2.size()) && list1.containsAll(list2);  an method to compare the object in list is need.